# Can I insert an attribute?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following imperative sentence:

> "Take a look at that group of people."

If I have to clarify how exactly I want a person (or persons) to look at that group of people--let's say cautiously, should I insert the word *cautious* between *take* and *look*?

> "Take a cautious look at that group of people."

Or should I say,

> "Look cautiously at that group of people."

Thanks in advance. Victor.

Comment: *"Take a cautious look at"* is more popularly used. *"Look cautiously at"* is also fine. (Based on Google search results)

Comment: Take a careful look at this comment. Now look carefully at my comment above.

Comment: I wanted to find the information about the case somewhere in the manuals but, alas, found nowhere. Does that mean that any inserts of the attributes in the word combinations " to take a look" are possible? Are the sentences: "Take an attentive look at that man." or "Take an insensible look at his notes." grammatically correct and widely used in colloquial speech?

Comment: Or "to take a walk"? Let's take a short walk in that park.

Comment: Looks aren't that commonly referred to as being cautious in this context, but “take a good look at X” or “take a close(r) look at X” are both very common wordings.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are correct.

In the first example, the verb is *take*, and the object is *a look*. You are describing the object with an adjective (cautious).

In the second example, the verb is *look*, and you are describing how they should look with an adverb (cautiously).

Comment: Thank you, guys, for your quick and very usefull explanations. Your information was extremely important.